# Best data type to store long text like news, articles.

Tags: php, mysql

This is my problem when im trying to store news entry some of those entries are inserting but some are not. I don't know if the problem is on the data type. Im just copying some news i found in internet and paste it to my form. Can someone help me about this?

my database structure..
[image]

sample of the news that are not inserting. i copy this text in the wiki and paste it to my news content input. and didnt work.
[image]

sample of news that successfuly inserted
[image]

here is my code for adding.

```
 <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    session_start();
   $username = ucfirst($_SESSION['username']);

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= @addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $newsimage="img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];



    $sql ="INSERT into news (news_title, news_date, news_content, news_image) VALUES ('$title', '$date', '$content', '$newsimage')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="success-alert">';
   echo '<strong>Successfully posted!</strong>';
   echo '</div>';

  }




  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the  `$content = $_POST['content'];` to   `$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['content']);`

Answer (score 1):

Few things could go wrong here.

You need to use POST instead of GET while posting form data.

If data is successfully posted escape text before inserting it into the db with:

```
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['content']));
```

LONGTEXT is just fine for longer text. You don't need LONGBLOB unless you are using binary data (like pictures etc.)

Comment: I didnt use GET i used POST for that.

Comment: and i test your suggestion to put a mysqli_real_escape_string to my news_content the result is successfully inserted but the news_content is blank.

Comment: I this you put '  (appositive s) this is not work. You can replace your string.

Comment: sorry sir? What do you mean? what should i do?

Comment: You can not put this string; Example : Google is a best's search engine. But you can put Google is a best search engine. You cannot put ' this value

Comment: Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

Comment: But i inserted a new entry with  ' before and there are so many of it?

Comment: Oh why cant i insert it now? What should i do to fix that?

Comment: Look at the picture of successfully inserted sir. There are so many ' there why is that successfully inserted?

Comment: You can put this in ajax

Comment: `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); 


$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);`

Comment: where should i put that?

Comment: You use this function and it's work properly i try it `function mysql_escape_mimic($inp) { 
    if(is_array($inp)) 
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp); 

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
    } 

    return $inp; 
} 
`